# GCC ignores -funroll-loop parameter

Tags: c++, c, gcc

GCC just ignores `-funroll-loops` and `-funroll-all-loops` options.

[Here is a code example](https://godbolt.org/z/YfG93GqT6):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void NOT_WORK_1(char* arg)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%s", arg);
    }
}

__attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops")))
void NOT_WORK_2(char* arg)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%s", arg);
    }
}

#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("unroll-loops")
void NOT_WORK_3(char* arg)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%s", arg);
    }
}
#pragma GCC pop_options

void WORKS_1(char* arg)
{
    #pragma GCC unroll(4)
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%s", arg);
    }
}
```

Compiled ass `gcc -O3 -funroll-loops`. ASM output

```
.LC0:
        .string "%s"
NOT_WORK_1:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rdi
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 4
        sub     rsp, 8
.L2:
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        sub     ebx, 1
        jne     .L2
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
NOT_WORK_2:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rdi
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 4
        sub     rsp, 8
.L7:
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        sub     ebx, 1
        jne     .L7
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
NOT_WORK_3:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rdi
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 4
        sub     rsp, 8
.L11:
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        sub     ebx, 1
        jne     .L11
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
WORKS_1:
        push    rbp
        mov     rsi, rdi
        mov     rbp, rdi
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        jmp     printf
```

If you look at the code you'll see that I've tried:

- Passing '-funroll-loops' via command line arguments during compilation
- Using `#pragma GCC optimize ("unroll-loops")`
- Using `__attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops")))`

GCC has special [pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Loop-Specific-Pragmas.html), but it is available only for GCC >= 8, but I have to compile with GCC 7.5.0, in which it is not available. Is there any way to force old GCC behave just like `#pragma GCC unroll N`?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler thinks that unrolling the loop is not possible, or that it's not optimal in this specific case? Though looking at the code (and the successful unrolling in one case) that seems unlikely.

Comment: These options are just a suggestion to the compiler which it can take or leave.

Comment: By the way, putting in a `main` function which calls the functions *inlines* the functions (but not unrolled, except `WORKS_1`).

Comment: clang 12 unrolls all those https://godbolt.org/z/eEYqvjb5r

Comment: Please show your command line.

Comment: You could file a bug in gcc's bugzilla, so they either unroll loops even when there is a call and the code size grows, or they improve the documentation of the option.

Comment: Add `\n` to the format string and watch magic happening right before your eyes ;)

Comment: It isn't obliged to unroll them. I'm a compiler writer and I wouldn't unroll these loops either. There is little benefit when all they do is call a library function. If it was heavy computation instead it would be a different story.

Comment: I agree with the fact, that those flags are only suggestions to compiler but not instructions. In my real code I do not call library functions, I call `inline` function with couple of intrinsics inside, but GCC complier still ignores unrolling flags. Hence, my question was not about the flags, but about the way to force old compiler behave like `pragma GCC unroll` in new compilers